# FINDSTR Batch Command truncates the file

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I am having a batch script to copy only the lines with a specific string to another file. The lines will be longer sometimes. I am using

> FindStr /I "string" file1 > file2

to do this operation. But in the resultant file, it is truncating the lines to 1024 characters. Is there any limitation in the dos programming that, the text file lines should be this much length only? If there is such limitation, then is there something we can set to override this behaviour.

Cheers, PK

Comment: Could the issue be with the program you use to display/process `file2`. How do you determine its lines are truncated?

Comment: Does it do it if you use  type file1 > file2 ?

Comment: My java program is handling the file2 and is throwing the error. When I opened using wordpad, i could see that it is truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a specific limitation to *your* `findstr`. For what it's worth, the one I have under XP SP3 works fine up to at least 2000-character lines <sup>(a)</sup>.

If yours *is* deficient in some way. you may want to think about either downloading [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com) or the `grep` tool from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) (search for grep in the package list) and using that instead. But as I say, based on my experience, it shouldn't be.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I created a single-line file with 2000 characters (repeating sequence of `1234567890`) and then:

```
C:\Pax> \cygwin\bin\wc xyz.txt
   1    1 2002 xyz.txt

C:\Pax> findstr /i "123" xyz.txt >xyz2.txt

C:\Pax> \cygwin\bin\wc xyz2.txt
   1    1 2002 xyz2.txt
```

Comment: This batch script is run over our server and there is no cygwin or GnuWin32 installed and unfortunately we dont have permission to install them also. :'-(

Comment: yes pax, it is working, but if you use find instead of findstr it still doesnt work. :-)